# Avoid "End of Field" in TalkBack of Accessibility in Android?

Tags: android, accessibility

Currently, I am facing an issue in Talk back functionality of Android. Whenever, Talk Back is ON in Android Device & tries to type anything in edit text then it will always speaks for "end of field" after typing every character. It is default in Android but is there any way to avoid speaking of this part "end of field" while typing during Accessibility Mode ON?
Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to turn this off?

Comment: After every character typing, it speaks out for "End of field" which is a bit of confusing.

Comment: Have your disabled users complained? At what states should the a11y service determine when to announce that it's there and when not to? I'm trying to think of what behaviour you are expecting, it's erring on the side of caution and this would be the same behaviour in other apps, right?

Comment: What I am ultimately trying to suggest is that if this is the same experience on all apps on the phone, wouldn't you be creating an experience that is inconsistant on that device? Sometimes these "requirements" come from a personal expectation and not from actual user requirements. If you are modifying the default behaviour it can be jarring for people.

Comment: I totally understand related to changing this default behavior. But, I got suggestion from live users who are using this feature in my application. So, I am just checking the possibility of it.

Comment: Ok I created an EditText on Google Pixel 5 with GBoard and it doesn't say "end of field" very often, only when I select the end of the field. Not as much as you are suggesting. What Model phone are you using and can you tell me the version of TalkBack? Mine is 12.1 (At the bottom of TalkBack settings)

Comment: The version of talk back is 13.0.2 (In Samsung). When we enable the talk back & start typing then after every character we type the talk back itself say "end of field", as for example if we are writing "HelloWorld" string in edittext then by default the cursor is at last position in edittext. As, 1st I type "H" & the cursor is after H and says "end of field", then I type "e" & the cursor is after e(but obvious) and says "end of field" and so on. I have tested this on (1) Amazon Fire tablet, (2) Google Pixel 6, (3) Xiaomi 8 Pro, (4) Samsung M42 (5) One Plus 9.

Comment: Does it happen on other apps as well or just on the specific text field in your app? Are you modifying the text entry in some way that might be causing extra announcements?